# Prevent sending data to stdin if spawn fails

Tags: node.js, stdin, spawn

In my Node.js (v0.10.9) code I'm trying to detect 2 cases:

- an external tool *(dot)* is installed - in that case I want to send some data to stdin of created process
- the external tool is not installed - in that case I want to display warning and I don't want to send anything to process' stdin

My problem is that I don't know how to send data to child's stdin if and only if the process was spawned successfully (i.e. stdin is ready for writing).
Following code works fine if *dot* is installed, but otherwise it tries to send data to the child although the child wasn't spawned.

```js
var childProcess = require('child_process');

var child = childProcess.spawn('dot');
child.on('error', function (err) {
  console.error('Failed to start child process: ' + err.message);
});
child.stdin.on('error', function(err) {
  console.error('Working with child.stdin failed: ' + err.message);
});

// I want to execute following lines only if child process was spawned correctly
child.stdin.write('data');
child.stdin.end();
```

I'd need something like this

```js
child.on('successful_spawn', function () {
  child.stdin.write('data');
  child.stdin.end();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From the node.js docs: http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options

Example of checking for failed exec:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    child = spawn('bad_command');

child.stderr.setEncoding('utf8');
child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  if (/^execvp\(\)/.test(data)) {
    console.log('Failed to start child process.');
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried this code yet and it does not detect failed spawning at all, but this issue is solved [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/pull/6053). Detection is not my problem, I want to prevent parent from sending data to child if spawning fails.

Comment: Well, the link you mention says that error events are emitted when there's an error. I assume success events are emitted as well, then? Run your stdin piping logic there.

Comment: By a [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) the ChildProcess emits following events: Error, Exit, Close, Disconnect and Message. None of them seems to be the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at core-worker:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-worker

This package makes it a lot easier to handle processes.
I think what you want to do is something like that (from the docs):

```
import { process } from "core-worker";

const simpleChat = process("node chat.js", "Chat ready");

setTimeout(() => simpleChat.kill(), 360000); // wait an hour and close the chat

simpleChat.ready(500)
    .then(console.log.bind(console, "You are now able to send messages."))
    .then(::simpleChat.death)
    .then(console.log.bind(console, "Chat closed"))
    .catch(() => /* handle err */);
```

So if the process is not started correctly, none of the .then statements are executed which is exactly what you want to do, right?